# Find/Replace lines in SQL column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an HTML field which contains the HTML for an entire webpage that is extracted from a word document.

Within this HTML can be the following:

```
<p>Please refer to &lt;|Any combination of words|&gt; policy.</p>
```

Anything between the `|` and `|` I need to capture.  The trick is there are multiple `|'s` throughout the document, so it needs to only be the `|'s` between `Please refer to and policy`.

I then need to replace that with an HTML link `<a href="Any combination of words">Any combination of words</a>`

So if I ran the code on the below:

```
<p>Please refer to &lt;|Specific Policy Name|&gt; policy.</p>
```

It would replace this `&lt;|Specific Policy Name|&gt;` with:

```
<a href="Specific Policy Name">Specific Policy Name</a>
```

Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: So an entire page is stored in one row of the table?

Comment: Does it have to be done with SQL? There's not much you can't do, but that doesn't mean you should. At least look into CLR's and try creating a function in .NET that is accessible by tsql.

Comment: @Elias The HTML for a word document is in a column yes.

Comment: @JeffO SQL would be preferable as it is a one time thing.  Just fixing a miss-communication basically.

Comment: @JeffO if it is not possible in SQL I could also do it with LINQ.

Comment: It might be possible in SQL (Google "TSQL Replace wildcard") but if you can do it in .NET code, it's a lot better option

Comment: Do you use XML  or NVARCHAR(MAX) columns to store these HTML values ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean it is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    OldContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    NewContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (OldContent)
VALUES (N'<p>Please refer to &lt;|Specific Policy Name&lt;| policy.</p>');

WITH UpdateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT b.NewContent,STUFF(b.InnerText,b.StartIndex-5,b.EndIndex-b.StartIndex+10,'<a href="'+b.[Text]+'">'+b.[Text]+'</a>') AS ChangedText
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.*,SUBSTRING(a.InnerText,a.StartIndex,a.EndIndex-a.StartIndex) AS [Text]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%',t.OldContent)+21 AS StartIndex,
                    PATINDEX('%&lt;| policy.%',t.OldContent) AS EndIndex,
                    t.OldContent AS InnerText,
                    t.NewContent
            FROM    @MyTable t
        ) a
    ) b
)
UPDATE  UpdateCTE
SET     NewContent = ChangedText;

SELECT  *
FROM    @MyTable x;
```

Results:

```
ID  OldContent                                                    NewContent
--- ------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   <p>Please refer to &lt;|Specific Policy Name&lt;| policy.</p> <p>Please refer to <a href="Specific Policy Name">Specific Policy Name</a> policy.</p>
```

Comment: For testing you could use `SELECT * FROM UpdateCTE` instead of `UPDATE  UpdateCTE SET NewContent = ChangedText;`. Don't forget to use transactions (`BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT/ROLLBACK`) when you execute the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I tried to get this to work, but I am running into errors.  I changed `VALUES ()` to `select top 1 html from Documents` which throws the entire `HTML` into `Oldcontent`.  It throws this error `Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Line 12
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: @JamesWilson: Try to replace `PATINDEX('%&lt;| policy.%',` with `PATINDEX('%&lt;| policy%',`.

Comment: @JamesWilson: As you can see this solutions works. If you have problems then you should find those rows which throw an error and publish those values (HTML).

Comment: I was able to find the issue, it does indeed work.  And is very fast. :)

Comment: One more question.  I posted a question for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317635/dynamic-sql-query-and-problems-with-special-characters but some of my 'dynamic words' contain special characters such as the `& ampersand` which returns a `NULL` for that specific word.  Anyone around this?