# Dynamic SQL Query and problems with special characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

Right now I am running a query to find and replace a dynamic word within a document into a link.  It works just fine but returns `null` when there are some special characters.  Currently I am having issues with the dynamic word contains an `ampersand '&'`

Here is part of the content:

```
 <p>STEPS:</p>
    <p>
    <p>Please refer to &lt;|Cease &amp; Desist|&gt; policy.</p>
```

It is returning a `NULL` for `'Cease &amp; Desist'`

Below is the code I am using, what I need is for it to return the entire dynamic word even if it contains the ampersand.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PolicyName NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    DocumentID int not null,
    OldContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    NewContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (documentid,OldContent)
select documentid, html from IPACS_Document where PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%', html) > 0 and PATINDEX('%|&gt; Policy%', html) > 0 and documentid = 147;
--select html, PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%', html), PATINDEX('%|&gt; Policy%', html) from IPACS_Document where PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%', html) > 0;



WITH UpdateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT b.PolicyName, b.[text], b.NewContent,STUFF(b.InnerText,b.StartIndex-5,b.EndIndex-b.StartIndex+10,'<a href="~/Document/Details/'+ CAST(d.[documentid] as VARCHAR(200))+'">'+b.[Text]+'</a>') AS ChangedText
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.*,SUBSTRING(a.InnerText,a.StartIndex,a.EndIndex-a.StartIndex) AS [Text]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%',t.OldContent)+21 AS StartIndex,
                    PATINDEX('%|&gt; Policy%',t.OldContent) AS EndIndex,
                    t.OldContent AS InnerText,
                    t.NewContent,
                    t.PolicyName
            FROM    @MyTable t
        ) a
    ) b
    inner join IPACS_Document d on d.filename like '%' + b.[text] + '%'
    where d.categoryid = 3
)
--select * from UpdateCTE
UPDATE  UpdateCTE
SET     NewContent = ChangedText, PolicyName = [text];

SELECT  *
FROM    @MyTable x;
```

In the above query the most inner query `query 'a'` `InnerText column name [text]` is what contains the dynamic word.  This is passed to `table 'b'` as `[text]`.  Eventually in `@Mytable` the dynamic word is put into `PolicyName`.

How can I allow this to work when the dynamic word contains an ampersand or special character?

Comment: if your input html is xhtml compliant, you may want to consider inserting it into the temp table as xml and use xquery.  Your PATINDEX comparisons will change to xpath and special characters should get handle.

Comment: @Jim it is not sadly.  Testing it on an online XHTML direct input brings back over 150 errors.  It is html that is derived from a converted word document.  I'm hoping there are other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PolicyName NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    DocumentID int not null,
    OldContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    NewContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (PolicyName,OldContent,DocumentID)
VALUES (NULL,N'<p>STEPS:</p>
    <p>
    <p>Please refer to &lt;|Cease &amp; Desist|&gt; policy.</p>',123);

;WITH UpdateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT b.PolicyName, b.[text], b.NewContent,STUFF(b.InnerText,b.StartIndex-5,b.EndIndex-b.StartIndex+10,'<a href="~/Document/Details/'+ CAST(b.[documentid] as VARCHAR(200))+'">'+b.[Text]+'</a>') AS ChangedText
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.*,SUBSTRING(a.InnerText,a.StartIndex,a.EndIndex-a.StartIndex) AS [Text]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%',t.OldContent)+21 AS StartIndex,
                    PATINDEX('%|&gt; Policy%',t.OldContent) AS EndIndex,
                    t.OldContent AS InnerText,
                    t.NewContent,
                    t.PolicyName,
                    t.DocumentID
            FROM    @MyTable t
        ) a
    ) b
    --inner join IPACS_Document d on d.filename like '%' + b.[text] + '%'
    --where d.categoryid = 3
)
--select * from UpdateCTE
UPDATE  UpdateCTE
SET     NewContent = ChangedText, PolicyName = [text];

SELECT  * FROM    @MyTable x;
```

Results:

```
ID PolicyName          DocumentID  OldContent                                                                    NewContent
-- ------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  Cease &amp; Desist  123         <p>STEPS:</p> <p> <p>Please refer to &lt;|Cease &amp; Desist|&gt; policy.</p> <p>STEPS:</p> <p> <p>Please refer to <a href="~/Document/Details/123">Cease &amp; Desist</a> policy.</p>
```

Comment: And if you replace this line `SELECT  a.*,SUBSTRING(a.InnerText,a.StartIndex,a.EndIndex-a.StartIndex) AS [Text]` with this one `SELECT a.*,CONVERT(XML,SUBSTRING(a.InnerText,a.StartIndex,a.EndIndex-a.StartIndex)).value('(.)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Text]` then the values from `PolicyName` will be, also, decoded (ex. `Cease & Desist` instead of `Cease &amp; Desist`).

Comment: I can now get the `PolicyName` to show up, but I'm not sure how to get the correct `documentid` without joining the `ipacs_document` table on the `PolicyName`.  The document that contains the text links to another document by name with a different id.  For example this document is `147`, but the `PolicyName Cease & Desist` document is `265`.  So now it is building the link to `Document/Details/147` instead of `Document/Details/265`.

Comment: I also get errors when using the CONVERT I think because it isn't valid XML, poorly converted from a word document.

Comment: 2) Then you should use `REPLACE` function to replace  `&amp;` with `&`, `&gt;` and `>` and so on. Yes, **isn't nice if you want a T-SQL only solution**.

Comment: 1) I don't understand why you need this join between `b`  derived table and `IPACS_Document` if you already have this line `INSERT INTO @MyTable (documentid,OldContent) select documentid, html from IPACS_Document` ?

Comment: Yeah, this has been a pain sadly.  You have been a huge help however which is much appreciated.  If I have to do some stuff manually then it's no big deal, would prefer to get most of it done with some t-sql.  If it isn't possible to do the above showing of 'Cease &amp; Desist' and have the join then I'll just have to do some columns manually.

Comment: The PATINDEX items are searching through documentID 147 which contains the text `Please refer to &lt;|%Some Policy|&gt; policy%`.  But `Some Policy` is the name of a completely separate document (which I get the document id by joining the table on the policyname (category 3 is only policies)).  so instead of building the link which would link itself to the current documentid `147` I get the correct documentid `265` through the join so when they click on the link in the website it takes them to the policy document.

Comment: I found the problem...  More miscommunication with our third party.  They put 'Cease &amp; Desist' in the document, and in the Database Cease and Desist....  Sigh  thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would think your problem may be, not sure the conversion of what appears to be an html element into a table and using a table variable veruss a permanent or temp table (#temp).  I can get substrings evaluating index and pass them to a temp table just fine, I cannot to a table variable.  This is using SQL 2012 as my version.

There are potential issues with using a substring too, namely you do zero validation on proper formatted XHTML.  I would personally use an xml query and/or value parsing after casting the xhtml to xml.  However this would show the values as they ultimately appear and not be what you wish.  However I have given your substring method as well and it will still work if you wish the data to be kept as marked up.  Self extracting example below:

```
declare @X varchar(256) = ' <p>STEPS:</p>
    <p>
    <p>Please refer to &lt;|Cease &amp; Desist|&gt; policy.</p>
    <p>Just extra stuff ;lkasdlkjasdlfkjasdf;lasdjfl;asdjf;lsadjkf;dsaljfas;dljfsdalfjsadlkfjasd;lfk</p>
    </p>'


if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null
    drop table #temp
;

With a as 
    (
    Select 
        @X as AsIS
    ,   cast(@X as varchar(128)) as Truncated
    ,   PATINDEX('%Please refer to &lt;|%', @X)+21 AS  St
    ,   PATINDEX('%|&gt; Policy%', @X) as Ed
    --, cast( cast(@X as varchar(128)) as xml)  -- WILL BREAK ELEMENTS
    ,   cast(@X as xml) as AsXml
    )
Select
  Substring(AsIs, St, Ed - St) as SubStringMethod
,   AsXml.query('p/p').value('p[1]/.', 'varchar(256)') as xmlqueryvalue
into #temp
from a

declare @temp  table ( submethod varchar(256), xmlmethod xml)
;

--insert into @temp  -- WILL BLOW UP with
--XML parsing: line 1, character 18, illegal qualified name character
Select *
from #temp
```